# Looking for a webcam recording widget

Tags: widget, webcam, record

This may not exist, but if I was hoping someone was aware of a product (doesn't have to be free) that would allow you to embed a widget on a site where the user could create videos using their webcam.  Then you would be able to get those videos via API.  Like youtube's record from webcam feature (http://www.youtube.com/my_webcam) but without having to leave the site that needs this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it exists and it's called Nimbb.  Check out the API and the tutorials:

http://nimbb.com/Help/Api.aspx

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Perfect, that looks like just the thing!

Answer (score 4):

The [webcam feature from YouTube **is now embeddable**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget). You won't have to leave the website, it is free anyway, and you'll still have the video's on YouTube so they're easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout [viddler.com](http://www.viddler.com) they have an API and support webcam recording.